# Cancel method not working properly

Tags: visualforce, controller

```
<apex:page id="portalUserProfilePage" controller="EmployeeProfilePageController" showHeader="false" title="{!$Label.site.my_profile_page}">


    <apex:define name="body">
        <apex:form id="theForm">
          <apex:outputPanel style="padding:50px 50px 50px 50px" id="empDetail">
           <apex:pageBlock title="Profile" id="editUserDetail" rendered="{!isEdit}">
             <apex:pageMessages />
             <apex:pageBlockButtons id="editButtons" location="bottom">
               <apex:commandButton id="save" value="{!$Label.site.save}" action="{!save}" rerender="empDetail"/>
               <apex:commandButton id="cancel" value="{!$Label.site.cancel}" action="{!cancel}" rerender="empDetail"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
             <apex:pageBlockSection id="editUserSection" columns="2">

                 <apex:outputField id="editusername" value="{!emp.Name}"/>
                 <apex:inputField id="edittimezone" value="{!emp.Photo__c}"/>               
                 <apex:inputField id="editemail" value="{!emp.Tech_Personal_Email_ID__c}"/> 
                 <apex:inputField id="editphone" value="{!emp.Techila_Contact_Number__c}"/>
                 <apex:inputField id="editlanguage" value="{!emp.Emergency_Contact_Person_1__c}"/>   
                 <apex:outputField id="editlanguage1" value="{!emp.Employee_Status__c}"/>                 
                 <apex:inputField id="editlanguage2" value="{!emp.Skills__c}"/>                 
                 <apex:inputField id="editlanguage3" value="{!emp.Description__c}"/>                 
                 <apex:outputField id="editlanguage4" value="{!emp.Designation__c}"/>                 
                 <apex:outputField id="editlanguage5" value="{!emp.Date_Of_Birth__c}"/>                 


               </apex:pageBlockSection>

           </apex:pageBlock>         

     <apex:pageBlock title="{!$Label.site.my_profile}" id="viewUserDetail" rendered="{!!isEdit}">
                 <apex:pageBlockButtons id="detailButtons" location="top">
                   <apex:commandButton id="edit" value="{!$Label.site.edit}" action="{!edit}" rerender="empDetail"/>
                   <apex:commandButton id="changePassword" value="{!$Label.site.change_password}" action="{!changePassword}"/>
                 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
                 <apex:pageBlockSection id="viewUserSection" columns="2">
                     <apex:outputField id="detailusername" value="{!emp.Name}"/>
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale2" value="{!emp.Photo__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detailtimezone" value="{!emp.Tech_Personal_Email_ID__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale" value="{!emp.Techila_Contact_Number__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale1" value="{!emp.Emergency_Contact_Person_1__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale4" value="{!emp.Employee_Status__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale3" value="{!emp.Skills__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale5" value="{!emp.Description__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale6" value="{!emp.Designation__c}"/> 
                     <apex:outputField id="detaillocale7" value="{!emp.Date_Of_Birth__c}"/> 





                  </apex:pageBlockSection>
               </apex:pageBlock>


            </apex:outputPanel>
         </apex:form>
    </apex:define>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public with sharing class EmployeeProfilePageController {

    private Employee__c emp{get;set;}
    private boolean isEdit = false;
    Public string userid{get;set;}

    public Employee__c getEmp() {
        return emp;
    }

    public EmployeeProfilePageController() {

            emp=new Employee__c();       

        userid=Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
        List<Employee__c> empList = [SELECT id,Tech_Personal_Email_ID__c,Name,Techila_Contact_Number__c,Photo__c,
                                     Employee_Status__c,Emergency_Contact_Person_1__c,Skills__c,Description__c,Designation__c,Date_Of_Birth__c
                                       FROM Employee__c 
                                         WHERE id=:userid];

      if(empList.size()>0){

            emp=empList[0];   
            }                                     

    }

    public Boolean getIsEdit() {
        return isEdit;
    }

    public void edit() {
        isEdit=true;
    }

    public void save() {


        try {
            update emp;

            isEdit=false;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        }
    }

    public PageReference changePassword() {
        return Page.ChangePassword;
    }
    public PageReference checkSession(){  
        system.debug('checkSession method call');
        if(userid==null){  
            PageReference pg = new PageReference('/apex/HRMSLogin');
            pg.setRedirect(false);
            return pg;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference cancel() {

}


}
```

Clicking on cancel button page remains in edit mode

Comment: Your code is incomplete, cancel method's code is missing.

Comment: Your cancel method currently does *nothing*. It shouldn't even compile without a `return` statement. Have it set `isEdit = false`.

Comment: You do not have any code in `cancel`